# Need to find top run getter year - wise- Power BI DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI/DAX and need support with the rank/rankx function.

I have two tables

1. IPL Balls by balls

| Batsman | Batsman_runs | Match ID | over no | ball no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kohli | 1 | 999 | 18 | 3 |
| Kohli | 4 | 997 | 15 | 1 |
| Sachin | 6 | 994 | 2 | 5 |

2. Matches Details

| Match No | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 999 | 22 April 2008 |
| 2000 | 23 May 2009 |
| 3000 | 10 May 2010 |

What I need is who has scored the most runs(Sum of Batsmans_runs) year-wise

Somethings like

| Year | Batsman | Runs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | Marsh | 650 |
| 2010 | Sachin | 550 |
| 2011 | AB | 600 |

This works in pysark

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

window_1 = Window.partitionBy('Year').orderBy(col('sum(batsman_runs)').desc())
res_41=sum_bat.withColumn('rank',rank().over(window_1))
top_scorer=res_41[res_41['rank']==1].sort('year')
top_scorer.show()
```

In Power BI, I have tried this and it's not working

`years = RANKX(ALL(ipl_matches[date].[Year]),sum(ipl_ball_by_ball[batsman_runs]),,desc)[enter image description here][1]`